# SpringBoot doesn't start Tomcat it immediately exits with code 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Edit: I found out that its because of my module-info file. Whenever I delete it the code runs perfectly. Does anyone know why it is causing this issue?

I am having an issue with Springboot. My code immediately exits with code 0 instead of keeping the server running. I've looked at multiple threads here but they were all missing this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However, I did include this in my pom.xml. I am working with a multiple modules. I copied most of the code from a different project with only one module and somehow I think working with multiple is related to the problem I am having now.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restful-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Default -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javax.ws.rs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2020-12-06 16:26:03.845  INFO 10848 --- [           main] restful.RestfulServerApplication         : Starting RestfulServerApplication using Java 11.0.5 on DESKTOP-UU1HOTF with PID 10848 (C:\Users\root\Documents\Git\FHICT\tictactoe\restful-server\target\classes started by root in C:\Users\root\Documents\Git\FHICT\tictactoe)
2020-12-06 16:26:03.847  INFO 10848 --- [           main] restful.RestfulServerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-06 16:26:04.276  INFO 10848 --- [           main] restful.RestfulServerApplication         : Started RestfulServerApplication in 0.709 seconds (JVM running for 1.203)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Due to request in comments:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(RestfulServerApplication.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8083"));
        app.run(args);
    }

}
```

Github link:
`github.com/dmitrilisokonov/TicTacToe`

Comment: Do you have a MRE, e.g. a git-repository link?

Comment: @Turing85 https://github.com/dmitrilisokonov/TicTacToe 

I added it for you to this repo since it was on my schools gitlab. restful-server is the module I am working on right now.

Comment: What does the `main` method look like?

Comment: *FYI:* `spring-boot-starter-web` includes both `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, so you don't need to list those dependencies.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks I have removed one of them. You can view the whole project in my git link. I've also added it to this thread.

Comment: Don't show code in a comment. **Edit** the question and show code there, to clarify the question. Delete the comment.

Comment: Having a `module-info` file turns your code into a Java Module, which encapsulates the code for better security. This prevents Spring from finding your code when doing classpath scanning, unless the `module-info` file grants permission to Spring.

Comment: @Andreas How would I grant it permission?

Comment: @Andreas isi spot-on. I deleted the `module-info.java` in `restful-server` (among some other changes) and the server keeps running.